# Local branch of public repository

Tags: svn, version-control

Is it possible to create a "local branch" of an SVN repository?

I am working on a team that needs to build a new feature for lucene/solr, and maybe commit it back to the project. We want to be able to work in parallel, merge new versions of the lucene/solr trunk into the version we build, and we would like to be able to contribute our changes as patches.

I know this should be fairly easy if we use the github mirror of the source, but before throwing another vcs into the mix (we already use SVN for the rest of the project)..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are on site 2 years, and still not teached to **use search before asking** questions?! **USE SEARCH!!!**

Keyword: "SVN vendor braches"

Recipe (in short):

1. Create branch folder in repo (`mkdir`, not `svn cp`), link it with svn:external to upstream repo (without PEG-revision)
2. Copy branch to trunk
3. Edit-edit-trunk
4. Update from time to time branch, merge branch to trunk, resolve conflicts
5. Repeat 3-4

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to the search terms, and for your friendly tone while doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before when my company was using svn, but I wanted to be able to branch my new updates.  I used git and the git-svn plugin.  Here is a tutorial for it: http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial

Comment: @Rudi - Git-boys annoys me by advertising their drugs always there possible. I *don't* suggest **here** hg + hgsubversion, even it's more friendly choice for SVN-users, because **Occam Razor rule world** - pure SVN-solution is good in this case. Downvote means "this answer not useful", nothing more